# Value of input field chnaged in inspector but not in browser window

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I dont know why but the value of my text field does not change when back button is pressed in chrome

below is the link to the video on youtube you can see that the program is working fine in edge but not in chrome and opera.

video - https://youtu.be/zRPRMa4f_hk project file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Q7gxc-fvzkvftk769Qy51u60_Pxd4IU/view?usp=sharing

the problem is that when i press the back button in chrome even though the query string changes and the value of input text element changes in inspector it does not change in browser window.

[image]

Please help me guy anyone. Im stuck.

Comment: It seems that adding `autocomplete="off"` to form or input field would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write autocomplete = "off" in form